# What is JP-21 (Japanese Scart)

Tags: scart

I can barely find any information on this, all I know is that the cables look the same but have different pins. Can someone explain the story of why they look the same and if JP-21 is a standard in Japanese TV's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is a standard although I couldn't find a copy of it, it's called TTC-003 of the EIAJ standards of Japan.   Looks like EIAJ merged to form [JEITA](http://www.jeita.or.jp/)

Here's a [link](http://gamesx.com/wiki/doku.php?id=av:japanese_rgb-21) that seems to have the pinout.   It looks like TTC-003 was part of a larger standard, maybe someone will know more.  Keep in mind though it looks like this was around in the 80s so it's pretty old now and pre-dated the internet so maybe there isn't a digital copy.  Could be worth asking Jeita if you really want to know.

This is just a guess but it may have been superseded by this [D-terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Terminal) connector.

Comment: Any ideas on who made the original design and who the other copied the look? It makes it very confusing

Comment: This is just a guess, it's possible that Japanese companies were already making the EU connector or knew it was coming because they were involved in the standards.  There was a time when Japan was the place to manufacture cheap electronics.  The move to swap the pins could have been an attempt at regionalization, so that it wasn't easy to by or import lower cost Japanese electronics into the EU market.

Comment: almost everytime i see jp21 theres always the word "xrgb" beside it. it seems like a device made by a company. could jp21 be a proprietary cable for just this device?

Comment: I think it just stands for Japan 21 pin, here's an example of a cable from jst http://www.jst.ru/pdf/ERGB.pdf